# Jolt Array transformation

Tags: json, jolt

My input json is like

```json
{
  "primary": 5,
  "quality": 4,
  "design": 5
}
```

and output should be

```json
{
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Name": "primary",
      "Value": 5
    },
    {
      "Name": "quality",
      "Value": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

i.e I dont want all fields from input to be in array.

Could any one suggest how to do that using jolt..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "p*|q*": { // the attributes whose keys start with p or q
        "$": "Ratings[#2].Name", // array-wise loop through the generated indexes of the attributes after traversing two levels( `:` and `{` ) for the tree path 
        "@": "Ratings[#2].Value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **$** wildcard represents `keys`, and **@** wildcard represents  `values` respectively

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : For the new proposed case you might tweak the spec as below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "p*|q*": { 
        "$": "Ratings[#2].Name", 
        "@": "Ratings[#2].Value",
        "@1,ip": "ip" // call attribute from the inside of the object
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "Ratings": "MANY",
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  }
]
```

in order to prevent getting redundant `null` components

Comment: thanks @Barbaros. it worked.. but getting additional null in the output as below 
"resourceCharacteristic" : [ null, null, null, null, null, {
    "Name" : "name ",
    "Value" : "value"
  }

Comment: it is working when there are no other mappings in the spec.. but when there are other mapping it is giving additional null as mentioned above comment

Comment: is there any way to remove that null from output?